# Is everything null in Java eligible for garbage collection?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Just wondering if that when you set

```
obj1 = null;
```

the object is eligible for gc, is it also true that everything with a null value is technically eligible also?

I'm particularly wondering about arrays, say if you have something like

```
[obj1, obj2, null, obj3, null, obj 4, obj5]
```

Can the gc run and remove the null object so the elements are empty?

Comment: Objects can't be null, object *references* can. The GC will never remove a variable or array index. It can only clean up unreachable objects.

Comment: @shmosel ...and in turn, only objects can be garbage collected, not references.

Comment: The instance that `obj1` previously referred to *might* be available for GC after `obj1 = null`; but many other references could still be pointing to that instance, preventing it.

Comment: You're confusing objects with variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "null object", and null is the closest thing that exists to an empty reference. The key definitions are in the Java Language Specification, [4.3.1. Objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.1):

> An object is a class instance or an array.
>
> The reference values (often just references) are pointers to these
>   objects, and a special null reference, which refers to no object.

`obj1 = null;` changes the reference variable `obj1` to be null. If it previously referred to an object it no longer does so.

There may be other references that refer to that object, so that the object remains reachable, and the garbage collector will leave it alone. If `obj1` was the last reference to the object, it is no longer reachable, and is eligible for finalization.

Comment: Okay, thank you. Can I ask is it then that objects also hold references in that a class instance/array can have a null String etc.? Sorry, I'm a bit confused.

Comment: @mucashinto Yes, object fields are either primitives, such as an `int`, or are  themselves references that are either null or a pointer to some object.

Answer (score 6):

Garbage collection collects objects, it does not collect references to objects.  The idea of garbage collecting a null therefor makes no sense.  What GC does at the simplest level is notice when an object no longer has any references pointing to it, and at that time it will free up the memory.  It doesn't care how many references point to null, it only cares how many incoming references an object has.

SO no, GC will never remove nulls from an array.  That's not what it does.  Besides which, a null value in an array is perfectly valid and removing it would break many programs.